# Adding a single class on multiple elements in if/else statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, constants

I have a script which adds or removes a class to multiple div depending on a scroll position.  This works fine as is.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var sp = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var logo = document.querySelector(".logo");
  var btn = document.querySelector(".toggle-label");

  if (sp > 100) {
    logo.classList.add("fade-out");
    btn.classList.add("fade-out");
  } else {
    logo.classList.remove("fade-out");
    btn.classList.remove("fade-out");
  }
});
```

But I've recently ran across another script which achieves the same in a more eloquent/modern way.  (use of let, const & arrow function.)

And I am just trying to learn how I can add/remove a class on multiple div in this modern script.

```js
let scrollpos = window.scrollY
const logo = document.querySelector(".logo")
const logo_height = 400

const add_class_on_scroll = () => logo.classList.add("fade-out")
const remove_class_on_scroll = () => logo.classList.remove("fade-out")


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollpos = window.scrollY;

  if (scrollpos >= logo_height) {
    add_class_on_scroll()
  } else {
    remove_class_on_scroll()
  }
})
```

I've began by trying to use array like this.

```
var fade = [logo, toggle-label];


fade.forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.add("fade-out")
})
```

But I am stuck on how to incorporate this array into the if/else statement.  I just can't wrap my head around it.

I am not stuck on using array by the way.  I am just trying to learn how this can be done in any sensible way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute them in for the place where you add and remove your classes:

```js
let scrollpos = window.scrollY
var elements = [document.querySelector(".logo"), document.querySelector(".toggle-label")];  // get your elements
const logo_height = 400

const add_class_on_scroll = () => {
  elements.forEach(function(el) {         // loop to add class
    el.classList.add("fade-out");
  });
};
const remove_class_on_scroll = () => {
  elements.forEach(function(el) {         // loop to remove class
    el.classList.remove("fade-out");
  });
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollpos = window.scrollY;

  if (scrollpos >= logo_height) {
    add_class_on_scroll()
  } else {
    remove_class_on_scroll()
  }
});
```

Comment: Pete, I am not trying to modify the first script.  I am trying to add a class to multiple div in the second (modern) script.

Comment: Pete, thank you very much for the showing me how to do it!!!

I am confused on your annotation though.   According to your annotation, el.classList.add("fade-out"); <- loop to remove class  Huh?  Wouldn't opposite be true?

Comment: haha copy and paste error - got them the wrong way round, knew I had to change one but didn't edit the snippet and edited the wysiwyg directly

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support LET and/or ARROW-functions!
Your approach with forEach is not quite right.

```
fade.forEach( function(one_fade_id){
  document.querySelect( '#'+ one_fade_id ).classList.add( "fade-out" )
} )
```

or

```
fade.forEach( (fadeId) => { 
  document.querySelect( '#'+ fadeId ).classList.add( "fade-out" ) 
} )
```

Comment: "Not all browsers support LET and/or ARROW-functions!" <-of course, I am aware that I always need to do "caniuse"  This is just an academic endeavor so I am not worried about cross-browser support.

Comment: just checking .. and .. making sure nobody downvotes my attempt at an answer because I failed to mention "YMMV" ;-)